# Locally open Java graphical application window wider than SSH XQuartz

Tags: java, linux, canvas, ssh, x11

So I usually use my Mac to [SSH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Shell) into my school's server to compile and run all of my Java programs in XQuartz, and running the program in the school's computer lab with Linux on it would give me the identical output.

On XQuartz and Linux it shows me exactly the same output like this:

[image: screenshot]

But, when I try to run my program locally (to prevent the lag), 
the Java application that opens my program would look like this:[image: screenshot]

This window appears to be wider than my defined value, and I don't think my code's the problem. Is there any preference, or settings to change? Any thoughts?